# SSRS email subscription link only opens to the home folder

Tags: ssrs-2016

My email link when clicked takes me to the Report Server login and after I log in it takes me to the home folder screen instead of the report.  How can I fix this?

My URLroot in Report Server configuration is

```
    <UrlRoot>
        https://it-sql-devrpt.services.ads.abcd.efg/Reports/report
    </UrlRoot>
    <UnattendedExecutionAccount>
```

The link in the email is

https://it-sql-devrpt.services.ads.abcd.efg/Reports/report?%2FIncome%20Statements%2FWAN%20Revenue%20and%20Expense%20%20Report&ReportMonth=1&ReportMonth=2&ReportMonth=3&ReportMonth=4&ReportMonth=5&ReportMonth=6&ReportMonth=7&ReportMonth=8&ReportMonth=9&ReportMonth=10&ReportMonth=11&ReportMonth=12&ReportMonth=13&rs%3AParameterLanguage=en-US

and the report link when viewed in a web browser is

https://it-sql-devrpt.services.ads.abcd.efg/Reports/report/Income%20Statements/WAN%20Revenue%20and%20Expense%20%20Report

Answer (score 0):

I did a little bit trial and error and this is functional for me, but it will be different for you.

https://hostname:port/BIReportServer

Try to set up what you see in Report Server Configuration Manager in Web service URL->Virtual directory